# MySQL SubString to extract exact part

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, substring, mariadb

I have a challenge as for my lack of knowledge in SQL.

I have a column in my database where I save this:

```html
<div class="product-cover" style="border:none;">
<div class="images-container">
<div class="images-container"><img src="https://myurl.com/img/cms/_DSC6641.jpg" title="" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to extract the string "https://myurl.com/img/cms/_DSC6641.jpg" which is different for every row.

Is it possible to create a query to extract that exact part in between src="..." ?

I am using MySQL/MariaDB

Comment: why you want to do that with mysql, which backend language  are you using?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: why  you want to dig hole with spoon when shovel is provided?

Comment: Why not to use the SQL iteration since it wil run already? It will save me some data parsing latter on...

Answer (score 0):

I would use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col, '<div class="images-container"><img src=', -1), ' ', 1)
```

Comment: OP is saying they have multiple images and wanted to extract all

Comment: @sumit . . . I do not see that in the question at all:  "I am trying to extract the string "https://myurl.com/img/cms/_DSC6641.jpg" which is different for every row.""

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way using the reply from D-Shih

```html
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING( 
  pl.description,
  LOCATE('src="',pl.description) + CHAR_LENGTH('src="'),
  ( LOCATE('" title', pl.description)) - ( LOCATE('src="', pl.description) + CHAR_LENGTH('src="') )
 ) as url
FROM ps_product p 
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product=p.id_product)
```